# I can't install pycharm due to Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, anaconda

I've recently install anaconda and I'm using PyCharm as my IDE, but when I go to import some modules, they don't seem to exist, even though they were downloaded with anaconda. When I tried to download Matplotlib via the terminal I get this

```
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-six
 python-wrapt
 python-pkg-resources
 python-pyflakes
 pyflakes
 python-lazy-object-proxy
 python-logilab-common
 python-astroid
 pylint
 python-egenix-mxtools
 python-egenix-mxdatetime
 python-pyinotify
 python-sip
 python-qt4
 ninja-ide
 python-cycler
 python-dateutil
 python-pil:amd64
 python-imaging
 python-pyparsing
 python-tz
 python-numpy
 python-matplotlib
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can someone please help me with this, I'm quite new to Linux and I'm really confused to what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Below codes can be solved your problem;

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: I've entered those commands and I get the same error, as stated above! :/

Comment: What is your linux image? You can delete all linux image files and try again above command what I said.

Comment: As I'd just reinstall linux when I had this problem, I just reinstalled linux :/ (I got this error about 2 hours after reinstalling for the second time)